# jsprit shipment with single pickup and multiple delivery

Tags: jsprit

Is it possible to make a shipment that has a single pickup point but has multiple delivery point?

An example case I have is a bike messenger that has to distribute letters from a single point of pickup to many addresses, the messenger has to go to the pickup point first, then deliver the letters. I tried making multiple Shipments for this (one Shipment per address), but then the pickup service time doesn't make sense, because there's not much difference in picking up one letter vs 100 letters for example.

Then, I tried to make separate Pickup and Delivery jobs. I made constraints that lets Pickup jobs to be done first before the other Delivery jobs. Then I read the documentation of Delivery class, it states that the job implies pickup at vehicle starting point (or depot), so this approach doesn't make sense too.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Is there only one pickup point involved per bike? Also "but then the pickup service time doesn't make sense"... you can set pickup service time separate to delivery service time, so just scale it appropriately before calling a solution or make it 0 for the hundreds of pickups. That would be a more general solution if you wanted to do this with `shipments`

Comment: @roganjosh I'll try scaling like you said. It will make more sense if I can group the shipments first, because it's possible that there's more than one pickup point. Can I attach arbitrary properties to `shipment`? If not I'll just use the `name` attribute of the `shipment` to group them.

Comment: @roganjosh when you say "before calling a solution" do you mean before I do `vehicleRoutingAlgorithm.searchSolutions()`? Because, if I'm correct, I can only set the service time when I'm building the shipments

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't helpful there. I consider the vehicle routing algo as a bit of a black box. I have a real world problem and I need to figure out how to represent it in a way that makes sense to the algo, so when I "call a solution" I mean feeding a problem to `jsprit` as a whole, not one aspect of the package. "Can I attach arbitrary properties to shipment?" I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: it's fine, you've been really helpful :) .As for the arbitrary properties, I've checked, and I can't do it unless I wrote another version of `Shipment` that can contain like a `Map<String, Object>` attribute, but then the `VehicleRoutingProblem` won't accept it, since it only checks for instances of the classes under `com.graphhopper.jsprit.core.problem.job`. If I try to feed my version of `Shipment` to the vrp, it will throw an exception, complaining that my the class is not an `instanceof` the original `Shipment`, so I resort to using shipment names to keep my grouping information.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having a problem with this, I hope this answer can help.

Basically I just set the Shipment pickup service time to 0 just like @roganjosh said, but then I added the outgoing travel time with the pickup service time. That and a postprocessing after the solution is obtained should work.

This is based on a post on graphhopper board [here](https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/need-ability-to-influence-activity-arrival-or-endtime/1125/13)